# query to combine multiple records into one record in access and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

hi i have following module in access database for concate multiple record into one record

```
Option Compare Database

Function Concatenate(pstrSQL As String, _
    Optional pstrDelim As String = ", ") _
    As String

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open pstrSQL, CurrentProject.Connection, _
adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Dim strConcat As String 'build return string
With rs
    If Not .EOF Then
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            strConcat = strConcat & _
            .Fields(0) & pstrDelim
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    .Close
End With
Set rs = Nothing

If Len(strConcat) > 0 Then
    strConcat = Left(strConcat, _
    Len(strConcat) - Len(pstrDelim))
End If
Concatenate = strConcat
End Function
```

and here is my query

```
SELECT Po_Master.PoNo, Po_Master.PartyName, Po_Master.PoDate, Po_Master.DeliveryDate, Concatenate("SELECT ItemDescription & Chr(9) & Qty FROM Po_Detail WHERE PoNo =" & [PoNo]) AS OrderDetail
FROM Po_Master;
```

this query and function working on access database but when i call in vb.net it show me error oledb exception was unhandeld     Undefined function 'Concatenate' in expression.

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim str As String
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    str = "Select distinct PoNo,PoDate,DeliveryDate,PartyName,OrderDetail from SearchPo"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(str, clsconn.conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "SearchPo")
    dt = ds.Tables("SearchPo") 'creati
    'MyDataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgvSearch1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

User-defined VBA functions are only available to queries that are run *from within Access itself*. To get the same results in a VB.NET application you will need to retrieve the child records and "glue them together" using VB.NET code.

Comment: how to glue the togeter in vb.net

Comment: @zahidmahmood There are a number of different ways to do it. If I were faced with the task I would investigate using [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx), but you might prefer some other approach. If you search Stack Overflow you will find a number of questions on the topic.